# Folder isn't visible

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have the latest apache under Arch Linux. Here is the screen:

[alt text http://uppix.net/f/a/b/1f323092f2485e2f1e8e59c3744bf.png](http://uppix.net/f/a/b/1f323092f2485e2f1e8e59c3744bf.png)

```
[ockonal@wincode public_html]$ ls -l
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 10 ockonal users  432 May  2 16:48 site
drwxrwxrwx 11 ockonal users 1456 Feb 20 23:24 unvisible
```

Why?

Comment: Is there an `.htaccess` file inside the directory or does an entry for this directory exist in your Apache httpd configuration (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory)?

Comment: @joschi, yeah. I've enabled viewing of hidden files in filemanager but it won't show .htaccess file there O_o. So I removed it directly from console and the folder is shown now. Please, reply on my question I'll mark your asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache httpd usually won't show directories or files which require any sort of authentication (e. g. through Basic Authentication) or are only allowed to be accessed from certain IP addresses or subnets. This is a "feature" to prevent information disclosure.